# Windows System Sounds

Tags: .net, windows, winforms

Can anyone map the Windows `SystemSounds` to their corresponding `MessageBoxIcon` and provide a brief description of the intended action that triggers each sound?

SystemSounds:

- Asterisk
- Beep
- Exclamation
- Hand
- Question

MessageBoxIcons:

- Asterisk
- Error
- Exclamation
- Hand
- Information
- None
- Question
- Stop
- Warning